# Saving font to postgre

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am gonna have lots of fonts edited by users and wanna save font data to database.

Now, the first problem I have met is what should be the column field type.

`:String`, `:integer`, ? or `:myFONT`?

Is it possible , if possible then how?

Comment: Could you explain in more details what you mean by "save font data to database"? And a good thing would be to show some code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about storing the file which represents a font, you can store it as binary data or type `bytea`

Details on how it's done:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/binary-data.html